# What statistics can I use in a case study to measure pre to post test changes

Tags: effect-size, pre-post-comparison

I am writing a methods section on technical refinement in sport. The study will be on a single participant (Case study) what statistics can I use to measure pre to post-test changes?

I want to see if the intervention had a positive change on the baseline result.

Is visual inspection my best bet?

Can I measure effect size with only one participant?

Comment: To say much we will need more details, but have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your participant repeats the exercise often enough, you can get statistically significant results. Alternatively, you could use a Bayesian approach, which will tell you something even with sparse data.

But here is a spoiler: your intervention will very probably have a positive result, due to the [Hawthorne Effect](https://www.verywellmind.com/what-is-the-hawthorne-effect-2795234). This is the enemy of behavioral scientists. But presumably your subject is hoping for a positive result, and will be happy.